# send json to wcf service

Tags: jquery, json, wcf

OK I have been working on this for a few days now an it is starting to annoy me.

I have a page where the user can change the colour scheme.  And choose a logo for the page.

Using jquery to loop round all the items that can be changed ($(".brand").each)

and build up the data and finally send it to a wcf service as a json object, see below

```
$(".brand").each(function () {
    //use the title attribute to list the css properties 
    // you want for that element 

    //use the id with a prefix to represent the actual element
    // you want to brand, 
    //matching up with the item in the site's css

    //prefix 'c-' = css class so replace with '.'
    //prefix 'id-' = element id so replace with '#'
    //prefix 'e-' = element so just remove the prefix

    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("c-", ".").replace("id-", "#").replace("e-", "");
    var title = $(this).attr("title");
    var values = title.split(',');
    var property = "";
    var value = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      selector = values[i]
      value = $(this).css(values[i]);
    }
    var item = {};
    item["id"] = "";
    item["selector"] = id;
    item["css_property"] = property;
    item["property_value"] = value;
    json.push(item);
  });
  if ($(".imgbase").val().length > 0) {
    var logoUrl = $(".imgbase").val();
    logoUrl = logoUrl.replace(new RegExp("^data:image/[a-z]*;base64,", ""));
    var item = {};
    item["id"] = 1;
    item["selector"] = "";
    item["css_property"] = "";
    item["property_value"] = logoUrl;
    json.push(item);
  }

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://localhost:64177/BrandingService.svc/DoBranding",
    data: JSON.stringify({ CSS: json }),
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (msg) {
      if (msg.hasOwnProperty("d"))
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function (result) {
      alert("Failed to call service: (" + result.status + ") \n" + result.statusText);
    }
  });
```

Now this seems to create an array object, so my question is, what on earth should my service be expecting, and how do I read it? Assuming I am sending it correctly?  If I receive it as an object there is no error but the service has no idea what it is and cannot deserialize it.  I can't receive it as a List(Of BrandingCSS), this causes a 500 error,  I have a class (see bottom), That I am trying to use as a List(Of BrandingCSS), so how do I get the "CSS Object" into that?  I have tried the JavaScriptSerializer and Json.net, I am open to either to get a result, so if anyone can help, please do before I go insane.

```
    <OperationContract()>
  Public Function DoBranding(ByVal CSS As Object) As String
    Try
      Return "FOO"

    Catch ex As Exception
      Return "BAR: " & ex.Message
    End Try
    End Function
```

Class I am using

```
    <DataContract([Namespace]:="")> _
  Public Class BrandingCSS
    <DataMember>
    Public Property ServiceID() As Integer
      Get
        Return m_ServiceID
      End Get
      Set(value As Integer)
        m_ServiceID = value
      End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ServiceID As Integer
    <DataMember>
    Public Property selector() As String
      Get
        Return m_selector
      End Get
      Set(value As String)
        m_selector = value
      End Set
    End Property
    Private m_selector As String
    <DataMember>
    Public Property css_property() As String
      Get
        Return m_property
      End Get
      Set(value As String)
        m_property = value
      End Set
    End Property
    Private m_property As String
    <DataMember>
    Public Property property_value() As String
      Get
        Return m_value
      End Get
      Set(value As String)
        m_value = value
      End Set
    End Property
    Private m_value As String
    <DataMember>
    Public ReadOnly Property logo() As Byte()
      Get
        Return img
      End Get
    End Property
    Private img As Byte() = Nothing
    Public Sub New()
      Try
        img = Convert.FromBase64String(property_value)
      Catch ex As Exception
        img = Nothing
      End Try
    End Sub
  End Class
```

If you are wanting to see the services section in the web.config it is this

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="BrandingService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="BrandingServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BrandingService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BrandingServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

and a sample of the json sent is here

```
"[
    {\"id\":\"1\",\"selector\":\".mp-level\",\"css_property\":\"background\",\"property_value\":\"\"},
    {\"id\":\"1\",\"selector\":\".mp-level\",\"css_property\":\"color\",\"property_value\":\"\"},
    {\"id\":\"1\",\"selector\":\"#header\",\"css_property\":\"background\",\"property_value\":\"\"},
    {\"id\":\"1\",\"selector\":\"#header\",\"css_property\":\"color\",\"property_value\":\"\"},
    {\"id\":\"1\",\"selector\":\"#header\",\"css_property\":\"border-bottom-color\",\"property_value\":\"\"},
    {\"id\":\"1\",\"selector\":\"headerinput\",\"css_property\":\"background\",\"property_value\":\"\"},
    {\"id\":\"1\",\"selector\":\"headerbutton\",\"css_property\":\"background\",\"property_value\":\"\"},
    {\"id\":\"1\",\"selector\":\"footer\",\"css_property\":\"background\",\"property_value\":\"\"},
    {\"id\":\"1\",\"selector\":\"footer\",\"css_property\":\"color\",\"property_value\":\"\"}
]"
```

Comment: Is it RESTFull Service?

Comment: It is a WCF service within the website itself, I tried a RESTFull service as a seperate project outside of it and this gave the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, add

```
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
```

in your POST request header.

I haven't seen `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` in your service contract.

**C# Code**

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "CSSBranding",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string DoBranding(BrandingCSS[] css);
```

Note that your JSON and **BrandingCSS** class should have same parameters. For example, for "selector" in JSON, you must have "*selector*" property in **BrandingCSS** class.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class BrandingCSS
{
   [DataMember]
   public string selector {get; set;}
   [DataMember]
   public string id {get; set;}
   //Remaining properties here.
}
```

I hope you understood **C#** code.

**EDIT**
If you want to check what JSON your service should accept, override the **ToString()** method for your **BrandingCSS** class.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); // Available in System.Web.Script.Serialization;           
    return js.Serialize(this);
}
```

Now make an object of class **BrandingCSS**.

```
BrandingCSS bcss = new BrandingCSS();
string acceptedJson = bcss.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(acceptedJson);
```

or you can make a temp OperationContract and call these line of codes. Hit a break point there and see the JSON. After that, make a JSON that you just have seen in debugger and send request. See [500 Internal Server Error.](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html). And also you haven't shown your **Web.Config** file.

Comment: Change BrandingCSS to BrandingCSS[] in function parameter. I have updated my Answer.

Comment: Thanks, tried this and I am back to my Failed to call service: (500) Internal Server Error

Comment: Which JSON You are sending?

Comment: See original post for web.config services section and example json being sent

Comment: OK, well I have tried this with just sending one item through rather than an array and it is "Nothing" when it gets into the service.

Comment: Its probably due to wrong JSON input. Paste your JSON here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and check it.

Comment: yes, got it sorted yesterday, i was passing in JSON.stringify(json), when I should have been passing in JSON.stringify({ css: json })