# 405 Method Not Allowed (WCF Web Service) after Second Request

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, wcf

I know 405 is a CORS error, but my website is on the same server as the WCF web service.

[jQuery .ajax() POST Request throws 405 (Method Not Allowed) on RESTful WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333013/jquery-ajax-post-request-throws-405-method-not-allowed-on-restful-wcf)

My website/service appears to have a different problem. The first call to the Web Service succeeds. It is only when the user makes a change to the data and the web service is called for the second time that the 405 error is called. This happens on localhost and when I publish to another server.

Here is the service:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "MyService", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat =      WebMessageFormat.Json,
 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
 ServiceResponse MyService(SimpleRequest request);
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Is the second request any different from the first? If you only perform the second and not the first is it any different? my guess is the fact that it is second has nothing to do with your problem. You should look at the differences between the two requests to diagnose this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are sending right JSON. If it works first time, it should also work second time as well. Try changing `BodyStyle`:

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828141/send-json-to-wcf-service/21829680#21829680) if it helps.